# How to change port of a redirect recieved by nginx?

Tags: nginx, iis, redirect, rewrite

I have set up an nginx on my server. It receives all requests and pass them to an IIS server behind it. My problem is since my site is running on port 2000 sometimes it sends redirects to nginx that contain port 2000 and after that redirection users will not pass through nginx. I want to rewrite a rule in my nginx to get all redirects and set the port to 80 so users don't go directly to the IIS. I also can fix this by changing c# code but I don't want to make code changes.

Comment: Please post your current config and possibly a curl output to explain the issue a bit better. If the html code (from IIS server / application) contains a link to port 2000, it is easy to solve. Using c# code or using nginx's [substitution module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it, but I'll give it a try.

From what I understand, you have A running NGINX listening on :80 (maybe :443) and A or B (don't know if the IIS is running on the same machine, though I believe not since users seem to be able to reach it directly) running IIS listening on :20000.

If A is running both, you're out of luck, you can't get both NGINX and IIS to bind to the same port so you won't be able to do that through NGINX. However, you can use your firewall to have requests made to :20000 that do not come from localhost to be passed to :80. This also works in the second case should you want to go that way.

If A is running NGINX while B is running IIS, you can always set tell NGINX to listen on :20000 as well and pass it on to IIS.

In any case, if IIS is not meant to be reachable through other means than NGINX you should have a firewall rule preventing access to it from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your nginx config:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html